# timezone conversion in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a `datetime` column in my dataframe and I need to get the date out of it and put it in a separate column.

Format of values in dataframe:

```
column name: timeinutc 
value: 2019-03-20T20:00:29.6259945Z
Desired Output: 2019-03-20
```

So i tried this:

```
payers['eventtime']=pd.to_datetime(payers['timeinutc'],infer_datetime_format=True)
```

got result like this `eventtime: 2019-03-20 20:00:29.625994500+00:00`

Next thing I did:

```
payers['eventtime2'] = pd.to_datetime(payers['eventtime'].dt.tz_localize(None),infer_datetime_format=True)
```

it resulted in `2019-03-20 20:00:29.625994500`

I only want the date out of my `timeinutc` column

Comment: Take a look at [How can I remove a pytz timezone from a datetime object?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10944136/10716506), I had the same issue and that worked for me :)

Comment: payers['eventtime'].dt.date

Comment: @WeNYoBen it worked !! Thanks so much