# Remove timezone (+01:00) from DateTime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to delete the timezone from my dateTime object.
Currently i have:
2019-02-21 15:31:37+01:00 
Expected output:
2019-02-21 15:31:37

The code I have converts it to: 2019-02-21 14:31:37.

```
# Convert to date
mood['response_time'] = pd.to_datetime(mood['response_time'], utc=True)
# Remove +01:00
mood['response_time'] = mood['response_time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: So you just want to visually strip the TZ information or you want to convert to naive datetime or you want to preserve timezone? Things get a bit ambiguous time-wise when you do something like that.

Comment: Just visually strip the TZ information, thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944047/how-can-i-remove-a-pytz-timezone-from-a-datetime-object

Comment: already tried that. This: mood = mood['response_time'].replace(tzinfo=None). Returns this: TypeError: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tzinfo'

Comment: make user mood["response_time"] is a datetime object first.

Comment: That is what I did right? See my code... -> mood['response_time'] = pd.to_datetime(mood['response_time'], utc=True)

Comment: `mood['response_time'].replace(tzinfo=None)` is not converting to DT first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first line, the parameter `utc=True` is not necessary as it converts the input to UTC (subtracting one hour in your case).

In the second line, I get an `AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'dt'`. Be aware that `to_datetime` can [return different objects](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) depending on the input.

So the following works for me (using a `Timestamp` object):

```
mood['response_time'] = '2019-02-21 15:31:37+01:00'
# Convert to date
mood['response_time'] = pd.to_datetime(mood['response_time'])
# Remove +01:00
mood['response_time'] = mood['response_time'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
# -> '2019-02-21 15:31:37'
```

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility might be to take `tz_localize(None)`. So for example this works:

```
mood = pd.DataFrame()

mood['response_time'] = ['2019-02-21 15:31:37+01:00']
# Convert to date
mood['response_time'] = pd.to_datetime(mood['response_time'])
# Remove +01:00
mood['response_time'] = mood['response_time'].dt.tz_localize(None)
mood['response_time'].iloc[0]
# => Timestamp('2019-02-21 15:31:37')
```