# python compare two date strings with different format

Tags: python

Start time is in format datetime with :

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSZ (e.g., 2004-08-04T19:09:02.768Z)
```

My code

```
starttime = item['ListingDetails']['StartTime']
present_date = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=2)
startdate = datetime.strptime(starttime, 'WhichFormat')
if  startdate.date() < present_date.date():
    print('Relisting item :', str(itemid), starttime)
```

Is throwing the exception because i dont know which was the real format.

Goal is to see if start time is 2 days ago. 
I.E If item was relisted 2 days ago + then relist it now

Comment: I think yo get data from database and format does not match the python datetime format. check this SO answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/10944136/3210415](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10944136/3210415)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [converting-string-into-datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use dateutil.parser:

```
import dateutil.parser

starttime = item['ListingDetails']['StartTime']
present_date = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=2)
startdate = dateutil.parser.parse('2004-08-04T19:09:02.768Z')
if  startdate.date() < present_date.date():
    print('Relisting item :', str(itemid), starttime)
```