# Remove Z from DateTimeField in serializer

Tags: django, datetime, django-rest-framework, python-datetime, django-serializer

Is there a way to make my serializer print the datetimefield by default like this

```
 2022-03-28T00:00:00+00:00
```

Instead of this

```
 2022-03-23T03:16:00Z
```

I get the first output when I do this

```
return obj.time.isoformat()
```

Comment: maybe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10944136/14457833) will help you

Comment: No, it doesn't. thanks for linking that. I do not want to remove the time zone

Comment: A serializerMethodField with return obj.time.isoformat() not work for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Cause

If you look into the code of `django-rest-framework` in `serializers.DateTimeField` if datetime is UTC timezone, the UTC offset (`+00:00`) will get converted to `Z` as can be seen [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/f4cf0260bf3c9323e798325702be690ca25949ca/rest_framework/fields.py#L1239:L1240)

## Solution

If you want to make it reusable for `DateTimeField`, you need to create a custom serializer `DateTimeField` that inherits from `serializers.DateTimeField` and override the `to_representation` method by coping codes from `django-rest-framework` and removing lines that convert UTC offset string to `Z`.

```py
from restframework import ISO_8601
from restframework import serializers


class CustomDateTimeField(serializers.DateTimeField):

    def to_representation(self, value):
        if not value:
            return None

        output_format = getattr(self, 'format', api_settings.DATETIME_FORMAT)

        if output_format is None or isinstance(value, str):
            return value

        value = self.enforce_timezone(value)

        if output_format.lower() == ISO_8601:
            value = value.isoformat()
            # remove lines that convert "+00:00" to "Z"
            # See https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/f4cf0260bf3c9323e798325702be690ca25949ca/rest_framework/fields.py#L1239:L1240
            return value
        return value.strftime(output_format)
```

Then use this in your serializer instead of `serializers.DateTimeField`

```py
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    datetime = CustomDateTimeField()
```

## Extra

If you want to use it in `serializers.ModelSerializer`, you need to follow below steps

1. Create a custom `ModelSerializer` that inherits from `serializers.ModelSerializer` and set `serializer_field_mapping` attribute as follows

```
class CustomModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    serializer_field_mapping = {
        # copy serializer_field_mapping
        **serializers.ModelSerializer.serializer_field_mapping,
        # override models.DateTimeField to map to CustomDateTimeField
        models.DateTimeField: CustomDateTimeField,
    }
```

2. Use `CustomModelSerializer` instead of `serializers.ModelSerializer`. E.g.

```py
class LogSerializer(CustomModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Log
        fields = ["id", "created_at"]
```

Comment: Got it thank you, I will try this, I knew the cause of it replacing the offset with Z. Didn't find where the code resided, thanks! Also does this Z give me the timezone of the datetime?

Comment: In my understanding, the `Z` is a special case only for UTC timezone.

Comment: So only the datetime saved with time zone of UTC gets a Z? In my postgres DB, I can find there's a +05:30 in the ended. In my django project I'm using TZ=true and set the TZ to Asia/Kolkata

Comment: I guess my problem's solved now thank you for the detailed answer.

Comment: In my understanding, django stores datetime in the database as UTC time without timezone part. When the data got retrieved from the database, it will be converted to the timezone specified in the django setttings. Hence, you see +05:30 in the end. More details can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/timezones/)

Comment: @annonymous this isn't true today (unsure if it was true at the time of your comment). If you have a basic, unformatted DatetimeField in your model it will include the timezone offset in the database (at least with Postgres) of the form `+-XXXX`

Comment: @sherrellbc Yes, I might be wrong in the fact that django stores datetime in the database without the timezone part. Thank you for correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it is to specify the format you want in your serializer:

```py
class MySerializer(serializer.Serializer):

    my_date = serializers.DateTimeField(format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')  # Specify your format here
```

Comment: This doesn't print the time zone in +hh:mm