# remove timezone from timestamp column of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Data loaded with column as pandas date time:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', parse_dates=['timestamp'])
df


   user         timestamp           speed
0   2   2016-04-01 01:06:26+01:00   9.76
1   2   2016-04-01 01:06:26+01:00   5.27
2   2   2016-04-01 01:06:26+01:00   8.12
3   2   2016-04-01 01:07:53+01:00   8.81
```

I want to remove time zone information from `timestamp`  column:

```py
df['timestamp'].tz_convert(None)

TypeError: index is not a valid DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex
```

Comment: Would this post help answer your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944047/how-can-i-remove-a-pytz-timezone-from-a-datetime-object

Comment: that answer didn't work in my case. it demonstrated a single-column dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this solution to work the column should be `datetime`

```
df['timestamp'].dt.tz_localize(None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given strings in your csv like "2016-04-01 01:06:26+01:00", I can think of the following options:

```
import pandas as pd

# will only work if *all* your timestamp contain "+hh:mm"
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', parse_dates=['timestamp'])
df['timestamp'] = df.timestamp.dt.tz_localize(None)

print(df.timestamp.dtype)
datetime64[ns]

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp.str.split('+', expand=True)[0])

print(df.timestamp.dtype)
datetime64[ns]

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', parse_dates=['timestamp'],
                 date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.split('+')[0]))

print(df.timestamp.dtype)
datetime64[ns]
```